# Adding combobox to panel on click of a button - Ext JS

Tags: button, extjs, panel, handler

So i have the panel here with several components:

```
{ xtype: 'panel', padding: 5, height: 500, width: '35%',
                    //Query Builder
                    items: [
                        { xtype: 'combobox', padding: 5, fieldLabel: 'Search In', store: states, displayField: 'field1' },
                        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Add', itemId: 'add_criteria' },
                        { xtype: 'combobox', padding: 5, region: 'east', fieldLabel: 'Criteria 2', itemId: 'combo2', hidden: true },
...
```

I have a controller set up that listens for the Add button to be clicked. What I want to do is add on a combobox (and maybe also a textfield as well?) each time the user clicks the button. The comboboxes will be added to the panel going down vertically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I updated it for ExtJS 4.2.

I've made you a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/cmvQt/

HTML:

```
<div id="panel"></div>
```

ExtJS:

```
    Ext.require([
    'Ext.panel.*',
    'Ext.form.field.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){

    function addComboBox(){
        panel.add({xtype: 'combobox'});
    }

panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    xtype: 'panel', 
    renderTo: 'panel',
    padding: 5, 
    height: 500, 
    width: '35%',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Add',
            handler: addComboBox
           }]
    });
});
```